# What does this quote mean? "whenever anyone says, 'theoretically' they really mean, 'not really."

Tags: meaning

Whenever anyone says, 'theoretically,' they really mean, 'not really.'

Dave Parnas

Comment: What exactly is your difficulty here? Have you looked up the word *theoretically*? What do you think it mean? (You may be right). I searched very briefly on the Internet and it appears to be a well-known quote, I would suggest that it is an ironic and/or witty one.

Answer (score 1):

The quote takes a skeptical view. Parnas is saying that usually when someone says "theoretically," the idea is so far-fetched that it will most likely not happen, because everything except the near-impossible will have already been accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the context, I can't specifically read into Parnas intent.

In a general sense, however, this could be taken to mean that there is frequently such a large gap between theory or possibility and reality that to say "theoretically" about an outcome is likely be rather just denying its unlikelihood, for whichever reason.

In way, it's similar to anticipating that any sentence starting with "*In an ideal world...*" is going to describe an outcome unlikely to transpire because of the obvious differences between that scenario and the ideal one.

Comment: The other side is that if there was no divergence between theory and practice, there's no need to say anything about it at all.